# NDSolve kernel crash, affected by variable naming

Tags: numerical-integration, bugs

The following isolated example cannot be further simplified much to reproduce a crash. I've already submitted the issue to TechSupport, but it seems this is not an easily reproducible case, so I'm posting here to narrow down the environment in which this manifests.

---

**Be aware: the following example, when evaluated, might crash the kernel. Please save anything before experimenting with it.**

```
ClearAll[t, R, A, \[Alpha], F, P, r];
SeedRandom[1];
eq = {
   R'[t] == r[t] - (1. R[t] (A[t] + F[t] \[Alpha][t]))/(10. + R[t]),
   A'[t] == -0.05 A[t] - (1. A[t] (F[t] + P[t]))/(10. + A[t]) + (2. A[t] R[t])/(10. + R[t]),
   \[Alpha]'[t] == -0.05 \[Alpha][t] - (1. F[t] \[Alpha][t])/((1. + 
        2.718281828459045^(-100. (-0.5 + \[Alpha][t]/(
           1. + A[t] + \[Alpha][t])))) (10. + \[Alpha][t])) + 
     F[t] ((0.1 A[t])/(10. + A[t]) + (R[t] \[Alpha][t])/(10. + R[t])),
   F'[t] == -0.05 F[t] + (4. F[t] ((0.9 A[t])/(10. + A[t]) + \[Alpha][
         t]/((1. + 2.718281828459045^(-100. (-0.5 + \[Alpha][t]/(
              1. + A[t] + \[Alpha][t])))) (10. + \[Alpha][t]))))/(40. + \[Alpha][t]),
   P'[t] == -0.05 P[t] + (0.1 A[t] P[t])/(10. + A[t]),
   r[t] == 5., R[0.] == 0., A[0.] == 1., \[Alpha][0.] == 0., 
   F[0.] == 0., P[0.] == 1.,
   WhenEvent[t == 1000., {F[t] -> Clip[0.1 P[t], {0., \[Infinity]}], 
     P[t] -> Clip[0.9 P[t], {0., \[Infinity]}]}],
   WhenEvent[R[t] < 0.0001, {R[t] -> 0., R'[t] -> 0.}, "LocationMethod" -> "StepBegin"],
   WhenEvent[\[Alpha][t] < 0.0001, {\[Alpha][t] -> 0., \[Alpha]'[t] -> 0.}, "LocationMethod" -> "StepBegin"],
   WhenEvent[F[t] < 0.0001, {F[t] -> 0., F'[t] -> 0.}, "LocationMethod" -> "StepBegin"],
   WhenEvent[P[t] < 0.0001, {P[t] -> 0., P'[t] -> 0.}, "LocationMethod" -> "StepBegin"],
   WhenEvent[A[t] < 0., {A[t] -> 0., A'[t] -> 0.}, "LocationMethod" -> "StepBegin"]
   };

NDSolveValue[eq, {R, A, \[Alpha], F, P, r}, {t, 0, 3000}, 
 DependentVariables -> {R, A, \[Alpha], F, P, r}]
```

I expect a graceful termination and not a crash. Furthermore, If I replace the variable `α` with something else, the example evaluates as expected - but not for any variable. Some variable names which work for me are: `α` -> `aa`, `α` -> `ff`, `α` -> `k`. **Unfortunately, the various variable-renamings produce non-identical results.** This cosistently happens, with a fresh kernel, even after a [clean start-up](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464).

*Mathematica* 10.4.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit), Windows 7

(The idea behind the ODE system is that certain variables are clipped if below a threshold (0.0001 or 0), and both the function and its derivate are kept at 0 after that point.)

Comment: No such behavior on 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014), i have 6 InterpolatingFunction, i'm using ClearAll["Global`*"] instead of your construct

Comment: No problem with Mathematica 10.4.0 on Windows 10

Comment: The code in the Question did crash the Kernel on my PC with Mathematica "10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)" on Windows 10,  The crash occurs for `t` between `1918` and `1919`.  Note that a plot of the output seems quite spikey.

Comment: Thanks @bbgodfrey, at least I know that it is not my machine against the whole world. The oscillating, spikey behaviour is expected, but of course the present example has rather extreme numerical values for parameters..

Comment: I encounter crashes once every few months,  It seems to me that the FrontEnd should intercept such crashes and try to provide some useful information.

Comment: @Simon Could you please specify if your Windows is 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: @IstvánZachar No problem with my Mathematica 10.0.2.0 on Windows 7; 64 bits

Comment: @IstvánZachar, 64 bit.